# Creating input with onkeypress with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a input element with a expected html output of this:

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  maxlength="13" 
  value="DD/MM/YY 00:00.0" 
  onkeypress="dateTime()"
>
```

I tried doing this with the following jQuery code

```
var input = $("<input>",
  {
    name : newName,
    maxlength : newSize,
    size : newSize,
    type : 'text',
    value : newVal,
    onkeypress : dateTime()
  });
```

But I don't get the expected output

```
<input type="text" maxlength="13" value="DD/MM/YY 00:00.0">
```

**Question 1 : what is the description of this code, because I cannot for the life of me find anything in the jQuery documentation about this stuff (link would be appreciated).**

**Question 2 : what is the correct parameter to use to get my expected html result?**

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: *Link would be appreciated* -> what about `jquery.com`?

Comment: And where are those variables coming from?

Comment: What good is a link to jQuery if I don't know what the code is called?

Comment: @ComFreek the expected result is at the top please read carefully :)

Comment: @serupticious Here is a specific link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
onkeypress : "dateTime()"
```

instead of

```
onkeypress : dateTime()
```

that one executes the function.

```
var input = $("<input>",
  {
    name : newName,
    maxlength : newSize,
    size : newSize,
    type : 'text',
    value : newVal,
    onkeypress : dateTime
  });
```

or

```
input.on('keypress',dateTime);
```

In the callback, "this" represents the event target (input).

You can get values from the input by using `$(this).val(); $(this).attr('myattribute'); $(this).data('myvar');`

Comment: Thanks, what is called in jQuery so I can search documentation to know what the accepted parameters are

Comment: The jQuery method is called ;-)
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes
Any parameter is acceptable. They will be placed as html attributes.
Edited answer for jQuery 1.4. See doc for 1.8+

Comment: If I cannot use (), how do I pass parameters to a function this way?

e.g. dateTime("DD/MM/YYYY")?

Comment: You don't. You can add data attributes to the elements ({"data-myvar": 12}) and get the values back in dateTime() with $(this).data('myvar')

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you need to review the keypress docs on jquery:

http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

You need to look at how to use document ready event in jquery too and how the selector engine works. Your code should look a bit like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("input").keypress(function() {
         //do stuff
    })
})
```

Comment: What is the advantages of doing that over just a html attribute?